# Find value in range with comma separated values in excel and return YES NO

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to match quotes (values in column B, for example 636431) with quote numbers (values too) in column A. In column A the values are comma separated and I'd like a formula to tell me if the value in B1 is anywhere in the range of cells (A2:A612) in column A and indicate YES or NO in column C as a result.

[image: Table in the link below]

Thanks for your help.
Best,
Wallace

Comment: Possibly something like: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,A$2:A$612))))>0` in `C2` and dragged down. Though if you want to explicitly return "Yes" or "No" instead of `TRUE` or `FALSE` you need to wrap this into an `IF()`

Comment: The formula is not picked up. I'm looking for a true or false value in C2 that'd tell me if the value in B2 is available anywhere in column A and if so mark a yes or no in C2. thanks for the help.

Comment: Change C column from text to standard and then re-enter the formula ;)

Comment: @JvdV has right answer.

Comment: Thanks gents. It didn't quite do the trick so I used the 'Conditional Formatting' option > Highlight Cell Rules option > Duplicate Values on the entire data set. That helped me identify quotes that already existed from those that don't. The only issue is the cell with comma separated values. Those are missed but at least the universe is reduced.